# Get character widths for a font

Tags: winapi

I need to get the width for characters from a given font (for example Arial). Only the width of the bounding box, without spacing.

```
HFONT font = CreateFont(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Arial");
```

Using the created HFONT, is there a way to extract this information?

```
int MyGetCharWidth(HFONT font, wchar_t wch)
{
    // How to implement this?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`GetCharABCWidths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but be aware that it won't tell you about kerning, so it may or may not be useful depending on what you plan to do with the information.

If you want the width of an actual string of text, there are several functions that will measure it for you, like [`GetTextExtentPoint32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Those functions will include any kerning corrections.

Comment: I need only the width of the bounding box of the single character, without any spacings. Those functions seem to need a HDC instead of a HFONT, why is that?

Comment: You have to select the font into a device context, and then call the whichever function you choose to measure the text.  The reason is that the answer depends on the particular device you want to display the text on.  Things like the display device's resolution and capabilities may affect the answer.  A ten-point Arial "X" on your screen might be a slightly different size than one on my screen or your printer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
int MyGetCharWidth(HFONT font, wchar_t wch)
{
  HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL) ;
  HGDIOBJ oldfont = SelectObject(hDC, font) ;

  RECT rect ;
  DrawText(hDC, &wch, 1, &rect, DT_CALCRECT|DT_NOPREFIX) ;

  SelectObject(hDC, oldfont) ;
  return rect.right - rect.left ;
}
```

BTW this doesn't make sense:

```
HFONT font = CreateFont(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Arial");
```

You must specifiy non null values for some of the parameters, for example:

```
CreateFont(fontsize, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0,
                          DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                          CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
                          DEFAULT_PITCH, "Arial");
```